# Maxine Waters "passed 3 bills in Congress in 27 years"?

Tags: united-states, congress, government, voting-records

It is asserted [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0hkLVyrsmI) (time stamp 10:04) that

> My opponent [referring to Maxine Waters] only passed 3 bills in Congress in 27 years.

Is this true and how does an average person like me verify this assertion (and others like it)?

In my own effort to answer this, I looked into [votesmart.org](https://votesmart.org/candidate/key-votes/26759/maxine-waters#.W849gmhKhPY) and [govtrack.us](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/maxine_waters/400422). At a very cursory glance, the assertion seems false as Waters voted on more than 3 bills that at least passed the House. But I'm not confident in my judgment as this is the first time I think about checking this kind of assertion.

I have no stake in the assertion being true or otherwise. In the interest of giving the assertion some benefit of doubt, however, is there an interpretation of the assertion that makes it true?

Comment: Any answer to this question would detail how many bills she authored or co-sponsored, favoring the former.

Comment: How does a single number "favour" authoring? Does sponsoring count for 1/2?

Comment: As PolitiFact discusses extensively in [this article](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2008/mar/28/manipulating-bill-counts/), bill count is a wildly misleading way to measure a Congressperson's legislative output regardless of how you define it (and also there is a long history of playing fast and loose with the definitions to get the "right" result).

Comment: This question may be a better fit for Skeptics.StackExchange. What is the political question here? You just want to verify the statement...

Comment: @Trilarion Surely it is possible that things overlap?

Comment: @yurnero Yes, overlap is possible and then the asker just chooses. I still wonder what the political question is though.

Comment: @Trilarion A process to verify a politician's voting record seems right on topic to me. Plus this question generates answers and comments (please see below) that would look absurd in any forum but this one. Cheers.

Comment: @yurnero I think that they would not look absurd in Skeptics. They would look absolutely normal there too. They get similar questions.

Comment: I get similar claims in political mailers for the Senate race in my state: "Candidate X introduced 0 bills".  The ironic thing is that makes me (and I'd guess a number of people) MORE likely to vote for X, rather than less :-)

Comment: Seeing as how she's one vote in a House of 435, passing ***any*** bill, herself, would be a monumental accomplishment.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Hi, I'm indifferent one way or another. Just wanted to see how to verify the statement, which as indicated, wasn't made by me. I have no view on it.

Comment: I'm making a comment more on the silliness of the language and claims being made in our election hyperbole in the USA. - no one can pass a bill by themselves, they need at least 217 other people voting with them, so "Congressperson X did not pass any bills" is a pretty meaningless statement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The information you're looking for *is* available on govtrack.us, but you need to know what to search for.

In this context, "passing" a bill (without any qualifiers) generally means introducing it and having it become law.  It may or may not include bills which were merely co-sponsored, but in my experience, when they do, it's explicitly called out.

Given that, the [following search](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/browse#sponsor=400422&current_status[]=28&congress=__ALL__) will show you that she has, in fact, introduced three bills which were passed:

[image: govtrack.us with Congress=all, Sponsor=Waters, Maxine, stsatus = Enacted]

If you want to include [Concurrent Resolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_resolution), which are bills that both houses agree to but aren't actually laws, then she's passed five bills.  Simple Resolutions (bills that pass a chamber but don't even go to the other one) add three more, for a total of eight.  However, it's reasonable to not include resolutions, since they have no binding impact and are often passed without a formal vote.

She also introduced two bills which were not passed, but had some portion incorporated into another bill which did pass.  These generally wouldn't count as "bills passed", but are certainly part of contributing to legislation.

Comment: "Passing a bill means introducing it and having it become law" - If you say that *Congress* passed the bill, maybe.  But I've never heard this usage in reference to an individual "passing" a bill.  Can you cite a dictionary?

Comment: @Kevin - It's very much shorthand, but it _is_ in use. I don't know if there's a dictionary that would explicitly cover it, but [here](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2014/05/which-senator-has-passed-the-most-laws/455952/) and [here](https://www.quorum.us/data-driven-insights/three-freshmen-lawmakers-make-history-with-most-bills-passed-through-house/309/) are two examples of it being used. Note that the first article is explicitly "sponsored or cosponsored" and the second one is just "passed the House" (not become law). But the concept applies. That said, I qualified my statement.

Comment: Fair enough.  However, I think you might also want to link to [this search](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/browse#sponsor=400314&current_status[]=28&congress=__ALL__) as a point of comparison.  "Only three bills" is a meaningless number without context.

Comment: @Kevin I don’t have numbers on the number of passed bills that’s usual, and I’m not interested in calculating it. Thus, I take no stance on whether “only three” is noteworthy or not.  The question wasn’t looking for that larger context, just verification of the claim.

Comment: "...only introduced three bills..." I wonder a bit about the usage of "only" here. What is the average number of passed laws per member of congress and year and what is the average variation of this number (percentiles maybe)? Otherwise I would maybe remove the "only" since it could be seen as a bit judgemental.

Comment: My next question would be "is that unusual"? Looking at the search link provided in the answer, there are a lot of people with similarly low numbers, although it's difficult to find people with similar lengths of service to compare.

Comment: @Trilarion Removed. I was echoing the quote in the question (which *is* almost certainly supposed to be judgmental), but I can see how it could be misconstrued here. That’s probably what Kevin was getting at, too, but you were much clearer about it.

Comment: @Bobson Thanks for editing. I think it is more objective now. The quote is surely judgmental but the answer should only check the facts, not the judgement.

Comment: @Jontia You could ask that as a separate question. Basically asking for a histogram of passed bills per time and per congressmen. But even then not every bill has the same importance, so the question would be what these numbers mean and maybe one was just unlucky and all sponsored bills were voted down for some reason. Instead of measuring activity (I guess this is the judgment here) one would just measure mainstream-yness(?). In the end, the question is how to measure a politicians work.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're getting the full picture here.  Representative Waters did not introduce "only" three bills.  She introduced( and here I am treating "introduced" and "sponsored" the same) 338, 5 of which were enacted.

Comment: @MichaelJ. - I missed that checkbox, since it was set off from the others.  I've added another paragraph noting the two bills which were incorporated rather than being passed themselves.

Answer (score 14):

From the [Advanced Search for Legislation](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/browse?sponsor=400422#enacted_ex=on) page, it appears that Representative Waters has sponsored 5 bills since 1973 that have been enacted.  Three of them were enacted and signed into law and the other two were incorporated into other legislation and subsequently passed.  I would assume, to be charitable, that the two bills that "didn't count" were overlooked by mistake.

On that same page, you can see that she sponsored, or is currently sponsoring 338 bills from that same time period.